# mysqld won't start, apparmor blocked some file?

Tags: mysql, 19.10, apparmor, mariadb

I'm using ubuntu 19.10,and when I installed mariadb, it is fine but when I restart the computer it started got some error. I track down the error seems like `apparmor` blocked it from reading some file. Here the error:

```
Des 16 22:31:08 nitro kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1576506668.471:146): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/etc/ld.so.cache" pid=10347 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_m
Des 16 22:31:08 nitro kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1576506668.471:147): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.9.1" pid=10347 comm="mysqld" re
Des 16 22:31:08 nitro kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1576506668.471:148): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1.9.1" pid=10347 comm="mysqld" re
Des 16 22:31:08 nitro sudo[10285]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

I already edit my `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`

it looks like this for now

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld {
  /proc/*/status r,
  /sys/devices/system/node/ r,
  /sys/devices/system/node/node0/meminfo r,
  /etc/ r,
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ r,
}
```

How to solve this error so mariadb can start normaly? Thanks.

Comment: I just reinstalled and it is working properly. But I'm still want to know what happening